# A question of variational inequality on H. Brezis' functional analysis book.

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

On page 134, H. Brezis gives an example of the connection of minimization problem and variational inequality. Here I quote:

---

Suppose $F$ : $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a differentiable function and suppose $u \in [0, 1]$ is a point where $F$ achieves its minimum on $[0,1]$. Then either 
$$u \in (0,1)\text{ and }F′(u) = 0 \tag 1$$
or 
$$u = 0\text{ and }F′(u) ≤ 0\tag 2$$ 
or $$u = 1\text{ and }F ′(u) = 1\tag 3$$
These three cases are summarized by saying that $u ∈ [0, 1]$ and $$F ′(u)(v − u) ≤ 0\tag 4$$ $∀v ∈ [0, 1]$

---

I was really confused by this example. Here are my questions

$(a)$: If I were a high school kid, I would think $(2)$ is wrong. If $F$ achieve the minimium at $0$, should we have $F'(u)\geq 0$?

$(b)$: I couldn't understand how $(3)$ comes from. Why I can have $F'(1)=1$ if $F$ achieve the minimum at $1$?

$(c)$: $(4)$ should be the variational inequality. But to my knowledge, should it be 
$$ F'(u)(v-u)\geq 0 $$
This fact I use many times in Calculation of variations... Don't tell me it is wrong...

Please help me to understand this example. Thank you!

(for a moment I thought this would be a typo, but I would be surprised if a such good book can make this many consecutive errors...)

Comment: These are indeed strange statements. (1) is correct, (2) is a necessary condition for a local maximum at 0, and (3) makes no sense. Finally (4) is a necessary condition for a local maximum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right on all points.

The corrected version of (4) can be interpreted as saying that the directional derivative in the direction $v - u$ is non negative.

Comment: So, should we just have $F'(1)\leq 0$ if $F$ achieves minimum at $1$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.